# How to mock the functions in a python script while executing the script using python command

Tags: python, mocking, subprocess, python-unittest

I am trying to test a python script via python command using subprocess (Python27).  Is there way to mock the functions being used in the script when I am testing like this?

For example,

example.py

```
import example1

if __name__ == '__main__':
   result = example1.testfunction()
   print result
```

example1.py

```
def testfunction():
   print "testing"
   return True
```

I would like to test the `example.py` script like this
test_example.py

```
import unittest
import subprocess
import mock
from mock import patch


class Example(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('example1.testfunction')
    def test_example_script(self, mock_testfunction):
        mock_testfunction.returnvalue = False
        cmd = ["python", "example.py"]
        task = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
        stdout, stderr = task.communicate()
        print stdout
        self.assertFalse(stdout)
```

Basically the patch doesn't work in my code and output I get is

```
True
AssertionError: True is not false
```

Is there way to mock the `testfunction()` in `example1.py`?

Can I force the `testfunction()` to return `False` so that my output is `False`?

Comment: I didn't understand what do you want to happen when you run line `task = subprocess.Popen(cmd)`?

Comment: @ands I have updated the question with what I am expecting when I print `task.communicate()`. Please check again If that makes sense now

Comment: What do you mean by forcing the `testfunction()` to return `False`?  `testfunction()` returns `True` because you have set it to return `True` in your code (in file example1.py).

Comment: Why do you want to test by running subprocess? If it's a python module you can just import it in the test script and the patch will work. That's the usual way to test. If you launch a different process it will run the original code that lies in the py file. It knows nothing about the patch.

Comment: If your real code, not testing code,  needs to use subprocess, then, besides testing the python module the usual way you may want to mock subprocess and assert the mock usage was as intended.